# Release (drop) object being dragged

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using an OnMouseDrag event to move an object. Trouble I have is that unless the mouse button is released the object will not drop. I want to be able to have the object drop if dragged to a certain location on screen (2d). So even if the mouse button is still down drop the object.

Here is the code I am using:

```
void OnMouseDown()
{
    screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position);
    Debug.Log ("We clicked fire block!");
    offset = gameObject.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, gameObject.transform.position.y, screenPoint.z));
}

void OnMouseDrag()
{
    Vector3 curScreenPoint = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, gameObject.transform.position.y, screenPoint.z);

    if (curScreenPoint.x <= 1) {
        return;
            }

    Vector3 curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenPoint)+offset;

    transform.position = curPosition;

    isDrag = true;

}
```

Comment: Please read the tags before using them. The unity tag is completely different from unity3d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't understand one thing: this location is a portion of the screen or is a 3D location in the game?

Posting for both cases:

1 - Location is a 3D place in the game:

Use `Physics.Raycast` inside your `OnMouseDragUpdate` method to check if your mouse cursor is hitting the area it is supposed to release the dragged object (you'll need a game object with a collider representing the location). If so, simply do `isDrag = false`.

[Here's an example](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/34795/how-to-perform-a-mouse-click-on-game-object.html) of how to do the raycast.

2 - Location is a portion of the screen:

`Input.mousePosition` ranges from 0 (0%) to 1 (100%), so simply check the mouse position inside your `OnMouseDragUpdate` method to verify if it's inside the region that you want, and if so do `isDrag = false`.

Comment: I am checkin to see if the object has another object below it if not then fall to the ground. Like moving a boulder on a ledge whilst it is on the ledge you can drag it but once you drag it past the edge of the ledge it drops to the ground whether you have the mouse button down or not. I don't know how to cancel the mouse drag in code. I can't force the boulder to drop unless the mouse button is let go of.

Comment: just make a bool `isDragging` and set it to true in `OnMouseDown`. Then, at the beginning of `OnMouseDragUpdate`, do a `if(!isDragging) return;`. Also, set `isDragging` to false when you drop the object.

Comment: Thanks! That works great. As always I can trust stack overflow to get an answer. I asked the same question on the Unity forums and got no response.

Comment: Glad I could help! Yeah, most of the time SO works better for Unity than Unity's own system.